# How to pass credentials through a fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, fetch-api

I can't pass credentials to avoid of the authentication dialog when GET request is sending as health check to RabbitMQ API.
If I pass url with the credentials inside 
*(e.g. http://user:pass@localhost:15672/api/aliveness-test/%2F)*

it receives the error below -

```
rabbitCol.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials: http://user:pass@localhost:15672/api/aliveness-test/%2F
    at rabbitColChecking (rabbitCol.js:12)
    at allReqInt (allReqInt.js:5)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):108)
```

If I sending this request without the credentials inside the url it's actually sent the request ok but the authentication dialog pop ups in the UI and it's annoying and not a pretty as well.

**The request is below -**

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

    async function rabbitColChecking() {
        let index;
        const hostsRB = ['http://user:pass@host1:15672/api/aliveness-test/%2F', 'http://user:pass@host2:15672/api/aliveness-test/%2F', 'http://user:pass@host3:15672/api/aliveness-test/%2F', 'http://user:pass@host4:15672/api/aliveness-test/%2F];
        let lengthVal = hostsRB.length;
        for(let hostIndxRB = 0; hostIndxRB < lengthVal; hostIndxRB++) {
            index = hostIndxRB;
            let url = hostsRB[hostIndxRB];
            fetch(url, {method: 'GET', credentials:'same-origin', redirect: 'follow', agent: null, headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}, timeout: 5000}
        ).then(function (hostindxRB, res) {
                handleLedResponseRB(res, hostindxRB);
            }.bind(null, hostIndxRB));
            await sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

The trigger to send this request is a "onclick" function inside some HTML file.

I've actually tried every solution I saw in the net, but nothing solves this use case.

Answer (score 12):

You can send your user name and password with fetch using the *Authorization* header, like this:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    redirect: 'follow',
    agent: null,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'),
    },
    timeout: 5000
});
```

`btoa` is a function provided by browsers. If you want to use it on the server side, you can require the [btoa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/btoa) npm module to do the job.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but it still presents the pop up dialog. please see the updated code line below - 
            fetch(url, {method: 'GET', mode: 'no-cors', credentials:'same-origin', redirect: 'follow', agent: null, headers: {"Content-Type": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml", "Authorization": "Basic {{token}}" + btoa('user:pass')}, timeout: 5000}

Comment: Helpful answer! Thanks, Patrick!
Is it possible that the closing round parenthesis is missing?

Comment: In node/typescript: credentials is not a member of RequestInit