# Why fetch doesn't allow credentials in the url?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Using credentials in url with fetch:

```js
fetch('https://test:test@example.com').catch(console.error)
```

Results in an error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials
```

This is correct according to the [specs](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request):

> If parsedURL includes credentials, then throw a TypeError.

What is the reason to put a restriction like this?

Is using credentials in url a bad practice?

Comment: From security perspective it's a bad practice because URLs are being logged on servers, proxy servers, can be hijacked by man-in-the-middle. In HTTPS URLs are not encrypted, only request itself is encrypted.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781924/how-to-pass-credentials-through-a-fetch-request

Comment: https://neilmadden.blog/2019/01/16/can-you-ever-safely-include-credentials-in-a-url/, https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/26, https://github.com/w3c/resource-timing/issues/368, etc.

Comment: As you asked "Is using credentials in url a bad practice?"
Yes, it is very very bad and risky practice.

Comment: Plenty of reasons why but for an answer as to why they decided to make this a hard restriction, you'd need to speak to the specification authors. And really, it all just comes down to some individual or group's opinion 

Comment: These sorts of questions are really some of my least favourite to see on StackOverflow because while they might represent an interesting topic, they are very difficult to answer canonically. See [Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/283366)

Comment: @VladDX "*In HTTPS URLs are not encrypted*" - [sure they are](https://stackoverflow.com/q/499591/1048572)! And the credentials [would typically be sent in a header](https://serverfault.com/q/371907/492195) anyway, not as part of the URL.

Comment: @Bergi, today I've learnt 2 things  I'll remove my comment to not confuse people. But you could keep yours

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, they explain a lot :)