Fetch API returns 401 with credentials included after successful authentication
I am trying to access some data via HTTP request using the Fetch API in js with node. I should be able to authenticate via our login URI then get the data by making a request to another URI. This is all working in postman, but simply does not work when put into code:
const req = await fetch(process.env.LOGIN_URI, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        //login properties
    })
}) //returns 204 as in postman

const req2 = await fetch(process.env.DATA_URI, {
    method: 'PUT',
    credentials: 'include',
    body: {
    }
}) //returns 401, unlike postman

I have been reading and re-reading the fetch API documentation and SO posts to no avail. I should be able to just make my subsequent requests after authenticating without needing to mess with the cookies, in fact, you can't mess with the cookies when using the fetch API anyway. I've been a dev for some years but I am pretty new to javascript and web stuff, so maybe I missed something
Is there actually a solution for this or should I just shed a tear over the lost hours and switch to something like axios?

What kind of authentication is your LOGIN_URI using?

"I should be able to just make my subsequent requests after authenticating without needing to mess with the cookies...". This is actually not the case. How will the endpoint know about the identity of the requesting party if no identity information is provided in some way (e.g. cookies, headers, etc.)?

Are you familiar with the fetch API? I think this is answered pretty plainly in the documentation directly from mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#credentials . Additionally, cookie is a forbidden name, you actually can't modify this programmatically anyway

My point is that you actually need to supply the authentication information that you receive from the login response (1st request), when sending the 2nd request.

Perhaps if you supply some more details, e.g. how exactly are you testing these requests through POSTMAN, what kind of authentication is the endpoint using, etc. you can get some help over here.

My understanding is credentials: 'include' is supposed to do that, but it doesn't. I inspected req and req2 in the debugger and the login request returns with 10 cookies, but the next request only has 4

Remember, 'credentials' is all about "...what browsers do with credentials". You are running fetch in a Node.js environment.

Perhaps this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781924/how-to-pass-credentials-through-a-fetch-request

That is a really good point that I overlooked. I guess I assumed it would just work the same but if it doesn't I might not be able to use fetch at all then

You can actually make it work by inspecting what Postman is doing exactly and replicating the behaviour manually through the options part of the Fetch API (e.g. headers).

You need to share screen shut of Postman for login and data. it will includes HTTP method, header, input of body, output of body, authorization after hide of private data. It will help to get your question's answer.

What type of authentication are you using? I would think JWT or Sessions.

I believe the Node.js version of fetch() has no restrictions on setting the cookie request header. What it does not have is a cookie jar so you'll need to parse the set-cookie response header and use the value(s) in subsequent requests

Like I said before I'm not great with web stuff but I switched to axios and got this working in like an hour. I might keep messing around with fetch in my spare time but I consider this solved for now. I found that scraping the .ASPXAUTH cookie from the login response allowed me to make my data request without a 401 response
